# How to prevent the action in the partial view from firing when an action in content page is fired?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2

I have a content page that has a form (user registration). The page is created from a master page that has a partial view with a from (login). When the action in the content page is fired (user clicks on the Register button), the action in the partial view of the master page is also fired. How can I make sure that only register action in content page is fired?

Master page (Register.Master):

```
...
<!-- begin login box -->
<% Html.RenderAction("LogOn1", "Account"); %>  
<!-- end login box -->   
...
```

Partial View (LogOn1.ascx):

```
<% using (Html.BeginForm())
   { %>
   <div id="login_box">
   ....
   ....
<% } %>
```

and Register.aspx (created from Register.Master):

```
<% using (Html.BeginForm()) { %>
...
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

That's how the `RenderAction` helper works. If you just want to include some partial without going through the controller use the `RenderPartial` method instead:

```
<% Html.RenderPartial("LogOn1.ascx"); %>
```

Comment: Thanks, but it did not work. I'm getting following exception:
The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'xxxxyyyy.Models.RegisterModel', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'xxxxyyyy.Models.LogOnModel'.

Comment: @burakk, you can specify the model when calling the RenderPartial method as second argument. You need to pass an instance of `LogOnModel` which is what your partial seems to be strongly typed to.

Comment: I tried 
<% Html.RenderPartial("LogOn1", new xxxyyy.Models.LogOnModel()); %>

but still the LogOn1 action fires... I'm confused :(

Comment: @burakk, RenderPartial doesn't call the action. It includes the partial directly. There must be something else that is calling this action such as RenderAction helper. Also when you submit the form the action could be called.

Comment: When I look at the page source, there are 2 forms with the same action:

<form action="/Account/Register" method="post">

one for the login box (partial view) and the other one for registration. ı don't understand why the form from the partial view has the action method Account/Register?

Comment: @burakk, that's because you didn't explicitly specify which action and controller you want to be invoked in your Html.BeginForm helper, so it simply uses the current controller and action and uses the POST request. If you want to submit the form to a different controller and action pass those 2 parameters to the BeginForm helper.

Comment: Darin, thank you for your help so far, but I still could not solve the problem. I changed Html.BeginForm helper to <% using (Html.BeginForm("LogOn1", "Account")), and now two forms have different action methods. However, LogOn1 action still fires when clicked on Register button. When I debug the application, first the Register (POST) method is called, since no values are entered, return View(model) called, and then LogOn1 (POST) method is also called. Any further suggestions?